# Gitlab CI/CD with conditional scripts

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, conditional

Here is what I wish to do in GitLab CI/CD:
Whenever something is pushed into a specific branch I wish to have multiple scrips and CI/CD should decide which script should be run based on the pushed files list.

For example:

- IF anything changed in ./resources/assets/views/* then run SCRIPT1
- IF anything changed in ./database/* then run SCRIPT2
- etc...

Do you Lads have any idea for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#ruleschanges) keyword:

```
job1:
  script:
    - ./script1.sh
  rules:
    - changes:
      - resources/assets/views/**/*

job2:
  script:
    - ./script2.sh
  rules:
    - changes:
      - database/**/*
```

Comment: Holy  sh*t  dude.  This question is not  relevant anymore because it  was already done. :D But thanks for the answer, I've marked it, so others can see it.